# Python Conway's game of life - parallel optimisation

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, pyglet, conways-game-of-life

I have the following code for a simple and expandable implementation of Conway's Game of Life using Python and pyglet.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyglet
from pyglet import shapes

COLOURS = [(255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 155)]

class Board(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, box=10, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.ndarray.__new__(cls, (box, box), *args, dtype=int, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, box, *args, **kwargs):
        self.box = box
        self.conditions = np.array([
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ])
        self.PIXEL = kwargs.get('pixel_size', 10)

    def populate(self, array : np.ndarray):
        self[:, :] = array[:, :]

    def neighbours(self, i : int, j : int) -> int:
        return sum([
            self[i-1 % self.box - 1, j-1 % self.box - 1],
            self[i % self.box - 1, j-1 % self.box - 1],
            self[i+1 % self.box - 1, j-1 % self.box - 1],
            self[i-1 % self.box - 1, j % self.box - 1],
            self[i+1 % self.box - 1, j % self.box - 1],
            self[i-1 % self.box - 1, j+1 % self.box - 1],
            self[i % self.box - 1, j+1 % self.box - 1],
            self[i+1 % self.box - 1, j+1 % self.box - 1],
        ])

    def next(self):
        new = Board(self.box)
        for i, row in enumerate(self):
            for j, idx in enumerate(row):
                neighbours = self.neighbours(i, j)
                new[i, j] = self.conditions[self[i, j], neighbours]
        return new

    def run(self, n):
        result = self.next()
        for i in range(n-1): 
            result = result.next()
        return result

    def render(self, dt, window=None):
        if not window:
            window = pyglet.window.Window()

        @window.event
        def on_draw():
            window.clear()
            for i, row in enumerate(self):
                for j, state in enumerate(row):
                    shapes.Rectangle(
                            x=self.PIXEL * i, 
                            y=self.PIXEL * j, 
                            width=self.PIXEL, 
                            height=self.PIXEL, 
                            color=COLOURS[state]
                        ).draw()

        if not window:
            pyglet.app.run()
        
        if window:
            self[:, :] = self.next()

    def animate(self):
        window = pyglet.window.Window(
                width=self.PIXEL*self.shape[0], 
                height=self.PIXEL*self.shape[1]
            )
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.render, 1./60., window)
        pyglet.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    try:
        size = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        size = 50
    board = Board(size)
    board.populate(np.random.randint(2, size=board.shape))
    board.animate()
```

I want to know how I can improve the performance (since at the moment the animation is much slower for a bigger size).

My main idea is to add parallelism to the `Board.next()` method and potential also the `on_draw()` function within `Board.render()`, to remove the double for loop. The main task of this function is to create a new instance of `Board` (essentially just a new `np.ndarray`) and update each cell:

```py
def next(self):
    new = Board(self.box)
    for i, row in enumerate(self):
        for j, idx in enumerate(row):
            neighbours = self.neighbours(i, j)
            new[i, j] = self.conditions[self[i, j], neighbours]
    return new

...

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    for i, row in enumerate(self):
        for j, state in enumerate(row):
            shapes.Rectangle(
                    x=self.PIXEL * i, 
                    y=self.PIXEL * j, 
                    width=self.PIXEL, 
                    height=self.PIXEL, 
                    color=COLOURS[state]
                ).draw()
```

I'm completely sure this can be done in parallel since we create a new array, and so I have the following questions:

- How could I do this?
- Are there many different methods to achieve this parallelism?
- Are there any other graphics-based optimisation related to the rest of the code that would speed it up?

Comment: Have a read here... https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#uniform-vectorization

Comment: thanks! really interesting and can see how it would help with performance, so will try to implement - however it's not strictly what I'm looking for - I'm looking more for multiprocessing/threading/mpi etc. things (although not 100% sure what this would look like)

Comment: Have you scanned the previous questions with a [conway] tag?  It's not entirely clear the `numpy` is the optimal tool for this.  Lists or even dicts might be better.  But I'm sure that's been explored by others.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339686/how-to-multiprocess-for-loops-in-python-where-each-calculation-is-independent) gives a link to [here (Parallelization: Conway’s Game of Life)](http://www.shodor.org/media/content/petascale/materials/UPModules/GameOfLife/Life_Module_Document_pdf.pdf) which seems useful

Comment: also regarding the optimal tool point - I'm using this as a way of learning parallelism so I think in this instance, i'm not sure that it's particularly relevant to the parallelisation question